# How to fix 16.04 blurry fuzzy screen?

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

Not getting a good display at 1900x1080 and have to use 1680x1050

It is quite blurry at 1900x1080. Can't even look at the screen without a headache.

Is there a way to fix it? I've upgraded what I can. Using an intergraded intel video card off a Dell laptop.

If you need specs please let me know the specific commands for the info.

Thank you.

VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Dell Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:0447]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

Comment: Are you sure it's 1900x1080 and not 1920x1080?  If yes, it's not a standard resolution and it has to be handled manually.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo on my part. Its 1920x1080. There was a warning in the 16.04 installation. The first popup window asked me about something, then said that this particular something was unstable, but there was no back button. In any case, it worked fine on the last version. There is also a green strip at the bottom of my screen on the 1920 resolution.

Comment: Ok.  Your video adapter data will be needed then.  Edit your question to include the results of the **VGA compatible controller** section of this terminal command `lspci -knn` please.

Comment: I've added the info in the original post, if you'd like to check it out.

Comment: This is really strange.  Can you add the results of `xrandr` please?  Are you using a VGA connection or is it DVI/HDMI?

Comment: Yes, I use an HDMI connection to my TV, with my laptop screen turned off. If I mirror displays I get a lower resolution because my laptop is a 720, where the tv is the 1080. I've tried switching hdmi cables but its the same result.

Comment: So, the problem occurs on your TV screen.  Does `xrandr` show 1920x1080 as an available resolution with a + next to it?

Comment: HDMI1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1212mm x 682mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
Those are some of the results from the command.

Comment: According to these results, 1920x1080 is not only available but it's also recommended.  What are we missing here?  It should be working just fine.  I'll see what I can find and in the mean time somebody else may be able to help too.

Comment: This only happened when I upgraded to 16.04, and after fiddling around with the TV settings and using different cords, I assume its something to do with U v 16. I've tried restarting and updating several times to no avail. But I do appreciate your time and effort, thanks again I hope I can solve it, otherwise I may have to downgrade.

Comment: The problem seems to be whatever this green strip is at the bottom of the screen. When I switch to 1920x1080 it is clear for about two seconds, then a green strip with white dots appears at the bottom, and everything goes fuzzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. Turned off a setting called 'Automotion Plus' under advanced options ON MY TV. Its there for 'fast action scenes.' Turning it off makes the fuzz go away, thin green strip still visible but screen isn't fuzzy anymore.

Comment: Is this setting on your TV?

Comment: Yes it is. But I just posted another question concerning this green strip on the bottom of the screen. Seems to be from 16.04 upgrade

Comment: This what we were missing.  Please mark your question as solved and mention in your answer that the setting was on the TV so that others won't try to find it on Ubuntu settings.

Comment: Just add the word SOLVED on the main title.

Comment: Adding SOLVED is not correct. Mark it answered please.

Comment: It won't let me mark the checkbox for another 23 hours.

Comment: No hurry; come back later to do it.

Comment: note for others: I had the same probleme with a traditional computer screen, and it was the "sharpness" parameter of my screen that needed to be increased

Comment: For me, I had to set the refresh rate to 60 Hz instead of 71.91 Hz.  I did not have this problem in Ubuntu 17.04, but do in 17.10 (artful).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juh_